# Convert char * to QString and remove zeros

Tags: c++, qt, codec, qbytearray

In my app I read a string field from a file in local (not Unicode) charset.
The field is a 10 bytes, the remainder is filled with zeros if the string < 10 bytes.

```cpp
char str ="STRING\0\0\0\0"; // that was read from file
QByteArray fieldArr(str,10); // fieldArr now is STRING\000\000\000\000
fieldArr = fieldArr.trimmed() // from some reason array still containts zeros
QTextCodec *textCodec = QTextCodec::codecForLocale();
QString field = textCodec->ToUnicode(fieldArr).trimmed(); // also not removes zeros
```

So my question - how can I remove trailing zeros from a string?

P.S. I see zeros in "Local and Expressions" window while debuging

Comment: Is the char array null terminated, when 10 bytes are set? `abcdefghij` or `abcdefghij\0`?

Comment: No this array will be only 10 characters without final \0, That whay I use QByteArray to say that my string can be up to 10 characters.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that `str` is supposed to be `char const *` instead of `char`.

Just don't go over `QByteArray` -- `QTextCodec` can handle a C string, and it ends with the first null byte:

```
QString field = textCodec->toUnicode(str).trimmed();
```

**Addendum:** Since the string might not be zero-terminated, adding storage for a null byte to the end seems to be impossible, and making a copy to prepare for making a copy seems wasteful, I suggest calculating the length ourselves and using the `toUnicode` overload that accepts a char pointer and a length.

`std::find` is good for this, since it returns the ending iterator of the given range if an element is not found in it. This makes special-case handling unnecessary:

```
QString field = textCodec->toUnicode(str, std::find(str, str + 10, '\0') - str).trimmed();
```

Comment: So what would happen if str will be 10 characters since it is not null-terminated?

Comment: That would explode. An easy fix would be to allocate memory for 11 characters and set `str[10] = '\0';`. Then it'll always be null-terminated.

Comment: In my case I read the data from file to structure when this field is part of this structure. So appending extra byte will be problematic.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, got caught up in meatspace. I added another way.

Comment: Thanks guys, I see the only way to trim null terminated string is making that by myself. It strange that Qt missing that.

Answer (score 2):

You can truncate the string after the first `\0`:

```
char * str = "STRING\0\0\0\0";                 // Assuming that was read from file
QString field(str);                            // field == "STRING\0\0\0\0"
field.truncate(field.indexOf(QChar::Null));    // field == "STRING" (without '\0' at the end)
```

Answer (score 1):

`QString` can be constructed from a char array pointer using [fromLocal8Bit](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qstring.html#fromLocal8Bit). The codec is chosen the same way you do manually in your code.

You need to set the length manually to 10 since you say you have no guarantee that an terminating null byte is present.

Then you can use `remove()` to get rid of all null bytes. Caution: `STRI\0\0\0\0NG` will also result in `STRING` but you said that this does not happen.

```
char *str = "STRING\0\0\0\0"; // that was read from file
QString field = QString::fromLocal8Bit(str, 10);
field.remove(QChar::Null);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Simon Warta, but that not works, i.e. this string still containts zeros. Qt docs says: _"QTextCodec::codecForLocale() is used to perform the conversion"_ so your solution is exactly like mine but just shorter.

Comment: You're right. I did expect that char arrays are cut before the first null byte but that is only the case if you don't set any length. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QByteArray>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "STRING\0\0\0\0";
    auto ba = QByteArray::fromRawData(str, 10);

    qDebug() << ba.trimmed(); // does not work
    qDebug() << ba.simplified(); // does not work

    auto index = ba.indexOf('\0');
    if (index != -1)
        ba.truncate(index);
    qDebug() << ba;

    return 0;
}
```

Using `fromRawData()` saves an extra copy.  Make sure that the `str`
stays around until you delete the `ba`.

`indexOf()` is safe even if you have filled the whole `str` since
`QByteArray` knows you only have 10 bytes you can safely access.  It
won't touch 11th or later. No buffer overrun.

Once you removed extra `\0`, it's trivial to convert to a `QString`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
char* str = "STRING\0\0\0\0";
QByteArray fieldArr;

for(quint32 i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if(str[i] != '\0')
    {
        fieldArr.append(str[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if this piece of code would do what it should, it is a nightmare to read and maintain. You are going to read this code like 1000 times more often than you write it and every time, you will spend like 3 seconds of valuable thinking time to understand what it is doing.

Comment: Say me, @Ute Riegel, is Assembler was you first language?